# Using decrement operator

Tags: c#, class, visual-studio-2012, operators

For my code, it is a number guessing game. They get 10 guesses before they lose, and it tells them if it is too low, too high etc. In my output when I'm telling them if they are too high or too low, I also wanted to display how many guesses they have left. But currently it tells them they have 9 guesses left every time and I'm not sure why.

The rest of the program works. So after 10 guesses it will tell them they lost, just every guess up until then it says they have 9 guesses left.

```
namespace NumberGuessingGame
{
public class GuessingGame
{

    int myGuess = 0;
    int guessesLeft = 10;
    int gamesPlayed = 0;
    int gamesWon = 0;
    int gamesLost = 0;

    Random rand;
    int number = 0;

    public GuessingGame()
    {
        rand = new Random();
        number = rand.Next(1, 100);
    }
    public void ResetGame()
    {
        number = rand.Next(1, 100);
        guessesLeft = 10;
    }

    public int CheckGuess(int newGuess)
    {
        myGuess = newGuess;

        if (guessesLeft < 1)
        {                
            gamesLost++;
            gamesPlayed++;
            ResetGame();
            return 2;
        }
        else if (myGuess > number)
        {                
            guessesLeft--;
            return 1;
        }
        else if (myGuess < number)
        {               
            guessesLeft--;
            return -1;
        }
        else
        {                
            gamesPlayed++;
            gamesWon++;
            ResetGame();
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Code for form class

```
namespace NumberGuessingGame
{
public partial class frmMain : Form
{
    public frmMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();           
    }        

    GuessingGame myGuess = new GuessingGame();

    private void btnCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int inputGuess = Convert.ToInt32(txtGuess.Text);
        int result = myGuess.CheckGuess(inputGuess);

        int guessesLeft = 10;


        if(result == 2)
        { 
            MessageBox.Show("You ran out of guesses and lost!");
        }
        else if(result == 1)
        {
            guessesLeft--;
            MessageBox.Show("Your guess was too high, try again!" + "\n You have " + guessesLeft + " guesses left");
        }
        else if(result == -1)
        {
            guessesLeft--;
            MessageBox.Show("Your guess was too low, try again!" + "\n You have " + guessesLeft + " guesses left");
        }
        else if(result == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You won!");
        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: do you use debugger? press F11 and see what happens line by line. trust me. debug will solve must of your issues, also it helps you to design better algorithms later and you will less fell into problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time the button is clicked, you set guessesLeft to 10, which causes the issue. If you make guessesLeft a private field it will be fixed.

Like this:

```
public partial class frmMain : Form
{
    private int guessesLeft = 10;

etc.
```

Comment: Would be better to not have two variables...expose the one in the `GuessingGame` class, instead.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 separate `guessesLeft` variables - one in your `btnCheck_Click` event method, and one in your `GuessingGame` class. Every time you click the button, it initializes a new `guessesLeft` and sets it to `10`, decrements it, and then the variable goes out of scope. You should only have one variable that holds that information, and the best place would be in your `guessingGame` class as a public property:

```
public class GuessingGame
{
    public int GuessesLeft { get; private set; }
}
```

and use that in your click event:

```
MessageBox.Show("Your guess was too high, try again!" + "\n You have " 
    + myGuess.GuessesLeft + " guesses left");
```

Comment: Not wise to make `GuessesLeft` set-able from the outside.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart yep. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void btnCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int guessesLeft = 10;
```

This `guessesLeft` is a local variable on the stack of `btnCheck_Click()`. It is destroyed when the function returns, and is re-created and reinitialized to 10 every time the button is pressed and the function is called.

You need to expose the `guessesLeft` from your `GuessingGame` class.  The best way would be via a read-only property:

```
public class GuessingGame
{
    // ...

    public int GuessesRemaining
    {
        get { return guessesRemaining; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are re-initializing the guessesLeft variable to 10 everytime the button is clicked. You instead want to query the variable from the GuessingGame object you created called myGuess.